# Socialite laravel 5.4 Facebook login error (ClientException in RequestException.php line 111)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

in past signup with Facebook functionality working fine suddenly when i signup or Login with facebook then i am facing this error

> ClientException in RequestException.php line 111: Client error: GET
>   https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?access_token=&fields=name,email,gender,verified,link&appsecret_proof=5fb0d218f94cb8024712269c053f0186d360efd82cd3b588eaf621e0c79c
>   resulted in a 400 Bad Request response: {"error":{"message":"An active
>   access token must be used to query information about the current
>   user.","type":"OAuthExce (truncated...)

i am using Socialite Package

Note: For some reasons i can't update composer or complete socialite package

Note: i had some changes in socialite packages for some purpose. if i update whole package then previous changes will be affect.. i did some changes in LinkedInProvider and GoogleProvider files.. i need proper solution for this error

My project is live and users facing this problem. any help will be appreciate..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same problem. I found that by updating to the latest version, the issue got fixed. [Socialite](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/socialite)

Comment: for some reasons i can't update composer or complete socialite packages

Comment: when i click on login with facebook. its redirect on facebook login page then i provide username and password and its redirect on my site with `code` then this error occur..

Comment: The solution is to upgrade the package. What is the error being thrown when you tried to update the package?

Comment: i had some changes in socialite packages for some purpose. if i update whole package then previous changes will be affect.. i did some changes in `LinkedInProvider`  and `GoogleProvider` files

Comment: I'd recommend to pull on an empty laravel project, pull in the SPECIFIC VERSION of the `laravel-sociallite` package you have in production, and do a diff in the command line to see what you changed. Try reverting the changes in dev, or try updating in dev and see if that does it. Good luck!